# How to Run Query Against Multiple Django Models in a View

Tags: python, django, model

How can I run a query against multiple Django models and display them through a template?

I have created two models, which I can query independently and render a response in their respective templates. However, what I want to do is submit my query through my Django form, have the query run against both models, and then have the results, if any, displayed on a single template. How can I achieve this?

**Models:**

```
class State(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    topic_list = models.TextField(null=True)

class Hearings(models.Model):
    url = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.TextField(null=True)
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
```

**Views:**

```
def state(request,query):
  data = state.objects.filter(text__icontains=query).values('text','topic_list')
  return render(request,'State.html',context={'data':data})

def hearings(request,query):
  data = Hearings.objects.filter(data__icontains=query).values('url','title', 'text')
  return render(request,'Hearings.html',context={'data':data})
```

Currently, I can query the models separately through my views. I want to run my query through a single view against both models. How should I do this?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question. But you can certainly run both queries in one view function (provided it accepts both `query` parameters, it appears they are URL parameters) and have it render a template to which it passes both resulting querysets. Why would you think you couldn't do this? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what you are trying to achieve but I will try and answer.

> How can I run a query against multiple Django models and display them
>   through a template?

Well the simple answer is that you can run queries against as many models in your view function or class as you want and add them to your context to be passed to your template.

for example:

```
def my_view(request):
    context = {}
    context['people'] = People.objects.all()
    context['pets'] = Pet.objects.all()
    return render(request, index.html, context)
```

in your template you can access the results of the queries as `{{ people }}` and `{{ pets }}` and loop through them etc. You can make more complex look ups using `Q` objects. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

> [..] what I want to do is submit my query through my Django form

Again you can get the data from the form submission and place it into a query

```
def user_input(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context = {}
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            pet_name = form.cleaned_data.get('pet_name') # get the name entered into the pet name form field
            person_name = form.cleaned_data.get('person_name')
            context['pets'] = Pet.objects.filter(name=pet_name)
            context['people'] = Person.objects.filter(name=person_name)
            return render(request, index.html, context)
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Again you would access the returned queries via the context you pass to the template. Also can build complex queries using Q objects. 
see docs for info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#the-view